# Laravel get/map with key

Tags: php, laravel

I was hoping I could do this on one line:

```
$users = [];
$rawUsers = User::select('id','first_name','last_name')->where('company_id',Auth::user()->company_id)->get();
foreach($rawUsers as $u) {
    $users[$u['id']] = $u['first_name'].' '.$u['last_name'];
}
```

I see the `Collection` class has a `->map` function which would let me do the concatenation, but I don't know how to get the results indexed by `id`. Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using `lists` method on the query:

```
User::select(DB::raw('concat(first_name," ",last_name) as full_name'), 'id')->lists('full_name', 'id');
// returns array(id => full_name, ...)
```

Or use `accessor` on the model and `lists` on the collection:

```
// User model
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['first_name'].' '.$this->attributes['last_name'];
}

// then on the collection call lists:
$usersRaw = User::where(...)->get()->lists('fullName','id');
```

Comment: Spent too long answering, you bet me to it!

Comment: @MarcelGwerder `lists` 2nd arg is the index.

Comment: I prefer to keep the strain off the DB, so I prefer your 2nd solution. Where are these magical attributes documented? And is there no way to do it with a closure?

Comment: @Mark it's at the very bottom of the eloquent docs, `$appends`.

Comment: You could do this with a closure, but that's what Collection is doing under the hood with `lists`.